# TDD verifying dependency method invoked correctly

Tags: unit-testing, tdd

I am trying to follow TDD in my proj but I can't get my head around how to verify I am calling a dependency correctly or even if I should be trying to verify it.  Here's the requirement:

Write an AddSalesOrderTask class that is responsible for adding an order to an ERP system.  The class can take any dependencies needed but must have an Execute method signature like this:

```
public class AddSalesOrderTask {      

  public override bool Execute(OrderData input) { 
     throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```

The AddSalesOrderTask.Execute method needs to map OrderData to ERPSalesOrder and then call IERPClient.AddSalesOrder.

I have an interface to access the ERP service like so:

```
public interface IERPClient {
    void AddSalesOrder(ERPSalesOrder order);
}
```

How do I verify that the mapping is done and then passed into the client?  Should I be testing both operations in this method?  To make this testable my first thought was to introduce an IMapper interface and pass it as a dependency to AddSalesOrderTask:

```
public interface IMapper<in TFrom, in TTo> {
    void Map(TFrom source, TTo destination);
}
```

Following TDD would this be a good first test?

```
    private AddSalesOrderTask _testObj;

    [Fake, UsedImplicitly]
    private IERPClient _client;

    [Fake, UsedImplicitly]
    private IMapper<Order, SalesOrder> _mapper;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void MyTestInitialize() {        
        Fake.InitializeFixture(this);
        _testObj = new AddSalesOrderTask();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Execute_MappedSalesOrderAddedToERP() {

        // Arrange
        var input = new OrderData();
        var salesOrder = new SalesOrder();

        // Act
        _testObj.Execute(input);

        // Assert            
        A.CallTo(() => _mapper.Map(context.Order, salesOrder))
            .MustHaveHappened();
        A.CallTo(() => _client.AddSalesOrder(salesOrder))
            .MustHaveHappened();
    }
```

Am I thinking about this correctly?

Comment: What exactly are you testing here?  That the method signatures are correct?  Unit tests are for  testing the *behavior* of your methods, not their invocation.  If you want to see how components will behave when they're connected together, you use integration testing, not unit tests.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: when I got this right, the responsibility of `AddSalesOrderTask` is just to orchestrate the calls to the mapper and to `_client.AddSalesOrder`. So the only behaviour which can be unit tested here is the correct invocation. Of course, if the orchestration is so simple, one can indeed question the need for unit testing such a class, and if an integration test might be the better choice here.

Comment: I see that my question is a bit confusing.  Let me rephrase.  If had a requirement that a SalesOrder needed to be added to an ERP system how would I do this in a TDD approach?  I guess at least 2 steps would be required: 1) mapping to SalesOrder 2) submitting to the ERP system.  How would I do this using TDD?  I could write tests for mapping and tests for submitting but is it necessary to write a test for the 2 steps combined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If had a requirement that a SalesOrder needed to be added to an ERP system how would I do this in a TDD approach?

In TDD you could start with unit tests for the mapper and the ERPClient, and afterwards add a test like yours for the `AddSalesOrderTask`. You can also switch the order and start with tests for `AddSalesOrderTask` first, especially if you want to do [TDD with stepwise refinement.](https://web.archive.org/web/20201025174155/http://geekswithblogs.net/theArchitectsNapkin/archive/2014/02/12/informed-tdd-ndash-using-mocks-to-allow-for-true-stepwise.aspx) But the more interesting question for your `AddSalesOrderTask` is, as @RobertHarvey has already pointed out in his comment, if the parts work together as intended. So if you want this to develop fully with TDD, you should also write an "integration test" for the parts, using the real mapper and the real ERP client. Note that [TDD does not necessarily mean to write only unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18988040/does-tdd-include-integration-tests).

An fully automated integration test will be more effort (and it will run much slower), since you will probably need a full test environment of your ERP system for this test, with a defined set of test data. If your ERP is a bloated monster, this can become a real pain, so you have to check if the fully automated TDD approach here is worth the additional effort, or if some (semi-)manual testing might be the better alternative. But if you think this might be working in your case, you can probably omit the unit test for your `AddSalesOrderTask` class (at least, as long as its responsibility is so trivial as in your case).

P.S.: I guess it should be

```
 _testObj = new AddSalesOrderTask(_mapper, _client);
```

in `MyTestInitialize`, you have to inject the two dependencies somewhere?